# How to upload the file in POST requests (form-data)?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, multipartform-data

I use this [GET request](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#file) `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>` which allow us to download the file from Telegram API.
Now I need to send this file in the second POST request (form-data).

*Right now my code raises such error*:

```
Exception: embedded null byte Traceback
```

*The code snippet*:

```
# Download the file via GET request of the Telegram API.
response = requests.get("{0}/file/bot{1}/{2}".format(TELEGRAM_API_URL, telegram_bot_token, file_path))

files = [
    ('file', (file_name, open(response.content, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')) # error
]

# Upload the file via POST request.
response = requests.post(FILE_STORAGE_SERVICE_API_URL, files=files)
```

*Question*:

How do I convert a file correctly so that a POST request can process it?

Comment: response.content is bytes which does not has encoding. Besides, I think you should give a runable code. I can not run your code because I don't have urls in your code.

Comment: @XuQiushi thank you for your answer. I tried to remove the `.encode()` method but the problem is still the same. Here I wanted to show only the concept without my credentials.  Please treat this with understanding.

Comment: Even though you want to keep your credentials, you should provide data like response. Without more information, I could just guess your problem. I think the response.content has '\0' in it. when you open file with '\0' in path, you will get this error. You can just try 'open('\0.txt')', it will produce the same error.

Comment: The data type of the `response.content` is `<class 'bytes'>`. In fact, the value of the `response.content` is very large. You can download the data from this temporary [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yh72hzli654esog/response.bin?dl=0). You can check it. It starts with the following values: `b'\x00\x00\x00 ftypisom\x00\x00\x02\x00isomiso2avc1mp41\x00\x00\x03Fmoov...`.

Comment: First, your content is a bytes. I dont know why you put bytes in 'open'. In fact, you should put 'file path' in 'open'. Second, python will treate your b'b'\x00\x00\x00...' as file path. If your filepath has '\0' or '\x00', you will get this error.

Comment: What do you recommend doing? Write a byte to a file and then open it by a temporary file path?

Comment: You alread had the file bytes. You can just try something like this 'requests.post(FILE_STORAGE_SERVICE_API_URL, files={'file': response.content})'

Comment: You were right. This statement is enough `files={'file': response.content}` to correct work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type of the `response.content` which I take from the first request is `<class 'bytes'>`.

The working code snippet:

```
response = requests.get("{0}/file/bot{1}/{2}".format(TELEGRAM_API_URL, telegram_bot_token, file_path))

files =  {
    "file": response.content
}

requests.post(FILE_STORAGE_SERVICE_API_URL, files=files)
```